# Express Redirect to index.html doesn't render app.js (React Refresh Cannot Get issue)

Tags: reactjs, express, redirect, single-page-application

I'm relatively new to React, but facing an issue which I understand to be fairly common; my app works fine, but when I refresh or try to link directly to a route, I receive the "Cannot Get /XXX" error.

I understand why I'm getting this error and I have read several threads here, as well as blogs and videos to resolve it, but have thus far been unable to fix it. I have been attempting a catch-all fix which routes through to my index.html.

on my server index.js:

```js
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/public/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})
```

When deploying this and I try a refresh, I don't get the error anymore but instead I am shown my blank index.html file. In other words, my app.js isn't rendered and I receive no errors in the logs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using a MERN stack with react router v6, the issue occurs when deployed onto Heroku (but not localhost). Could anybody help to point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
My frontend index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: your index has no js file, you should build react and send the one in dist folder. Try running the build command to see the difference between your current index and the built one

Comment: Thank you Jimmy for your response, much appreciated. In fact though, my project does have an index.js file (I've pasted this to the bottom of my initial post). I've compared this with a freshly generated project and they seem to match; public folder with index.html and a src folder with index.js

Do you have any other ideas as to what might be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: The html has to link to the js file, remember that when you run in dev mode, that linking process (html and js) is handled automatic for you (as you use some kind of scaffolding/pre-generated project). When you upload to a server, you have to do with production mode, which you do with the "build" command. So you can check my previous answer to see why I mentioned build step there

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. Coming back to this a couple of months later, but been trying to get my head around this off-and-on for quite some time. Your comments led me on to quite a bit of research and education around build and deployment. Previously, I was deploying my development code, without running npm run build. Even after running this, refresh still failed. This was because I was still sending my public index.html file on the * route, rather than the build index.html file. As soon as I swapped those out, everything is now working as expected. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Great I could help and I'm happy that you take your time and learnt new things! Congrats! And keep it up bro! Happy coding.